# Problems with setting up Selenium Grid2

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I want to study how to run same test at same time on two computers.
I've done everything that is explained in this [tutorial](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html).
I have PC, where I set hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role hub
```

And I have notebook, where is node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.0.50:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

So here is my code:

```
public class Driver
{
    IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\ChromeDriver\");

    public string BaseUrl, NodeUrl;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() 
    {
        BaseUrl = "http://google.com/";
        NodeUrl = "http://192.168.0.66:5566/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "VISTA");
        _driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(NodeUrl), capability);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        _driver.Quit();
    }
    [Test]
    public void SimpleTest()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseUrl);
        Assert.AreEqual("Google", _driver.Title);
    }
}
```

When I run test in VS2012, it gives me following error:

> SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

I searched. People gave advice to add environment variable from Control Panel in Windows. I did.

> webdriver.chrome.driver    C:\Program Files (x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe

That didn't help me. Same error.
I searched more. Next advice was to set this variable when I configure hub. Like this:

```
java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar webdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files(x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" -role hub
```

This also doesn't help.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT should be

java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files(x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" -role hub

Comment: Thank you for respond. I did, same error. Should I use -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files(x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" only when I register hub or when node too?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It works. I add -webdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Program Files(x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" when I register node.

Comment: I have another question. How to run mulltiple browsers with this test on my node? I add --maxSession 10, but it doesn't work. Only 1 browser doing my test on the node.